# PHP Magento get customers last order total

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

I am working outside of magento store root folder (1.4) and I would like to get customers order totals, and date of last order.  I have started with this:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($entity_id);
         $customerTotals =Mage::getResourceModel('sales/sale_collection')
              ->setCustomerFilter($customer)
              ->load()
              ->getTotals();

         echo $customerTotals->getNumOrders();
         echo money_format('$%i',$customerTotals->getLifetime());
```

This seems to be giving me totals from the wrong customer... Also, can't quite figure out how to get customers last order day.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work, giving you the total number of order, total sales and most recent order for a given customer.

The code could be shortened a little, but for clarity it is as follows...

```
$customerId = 2;
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFilter('customer_id', $customerId)
    ->setOrder('created_at', Varien_Data_Collection_Db::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
;
$numberOfOrders = $orderCollection->count();
$newestOrder = $orderCollection->getFirstItem();

$orderCollection->clear()->getSelect()
    ->columns(array('total_sales'=>'SUM(main_table.base_grand_total)'))
    ->group('customer_id')
;
$totalSales = $orderCollection->getFirstItem()
    ->getData('total_sales');

//Some output to confirm...
echo "<p>" . $numberOfOrders . "</p>";
echo "<p>" . Mage::helper('core')->currency($totalSales, true, false) ."</p>";
echo "<p>" . $newestOrder->getData('increment_id') ."</p>";
```

Comment: Drew, this is awesome!!  Is there any way to also pull the Date of the last order?

Comment: I used $newestOrder->getData('created_at') but wasn't sure if this was the account creation date

Comment: Yes, $newestOrder->getData('created_at') will give you the date the order was created